# Integrating external database to OSM routing engine

Tags: android, mobile, openstreetmap

How can i  integrate my external toll cost database into OSM routing engines? Is there any tutorial available? 
Thanks very much

Comment: Which routing engine are you referring to? There are lots of different [OSM routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Comment: Sorry, Im a totally newbie, im going to use OpenRoute-Service routing engine in my project.

Comment: What is your purpose going to do ? Applying routing algorithms on your database ?

Comment: My purpose is to calculate toll cost from a searched route. I found that i need to integrate an external database in order to calculate the cost. Or is there any alternative?